# StandardInput is not always redirected if StandardOutput is not (.NET)

Tags: .net, process, ipc

I want to execute external programs in a task queue to perform some checks on my data. Therefore I start an external process, feed it with data via StandardInput and read the ExitCode (Errorlevel) to see if the requirements are met.

In a concrete scenario I want to use the `find.exe` command to search for a text in a data file. It should return 0 if the text was found in the file. According to find.exe-help a `find.exe "Foo"` is supposed to read from StandardInput and search for the string "Foo".

What I don't get is the following: When I only redirect the InputStream and start the process, find.exe immediately returns with ExitCode 1 (indicating either string not found or input file not found). If I also redirect the OutputStream, everything seems to work fine.

I also tested with the `sort.exe` command (as the samples in .NET help show) and everything works fine without also redirecting the OutputStream.

Here's my simplified code (VB.net with .NET3.5SP1):

```
Dim inputFilename As String = "D:\Temp\names.txt"
Dim outputFilename As String = "D:\Temp\namefind.out" '* set to Nothing for malbehavior

Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("FIND.EXE", """Foo""")
psi.UseShellExecute = False
psi.ErrorDialog = False

Dim isr As StreamReader = Nothing, osw As StreamWriter = Nothing
If (inputFilename IsNot Nothing) Then isr = New StreamReader(inputFilename, True) : psi.RedirectStandardInput = True
If (outputFilename IsNot Nothing) Then osw = New StreamWriter(outputFilename, False) : psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True

Using p As Process = Process.Start(psi)
    If isr IsNot Nothing Then _
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub()
                                       Dim buf(2 ^ 13) As Char, cnt As Integer, pin As StreamWriter = p.StandardInput
                                       Do : cnt = isr.ReadBlock(buf, 0, 2 ^ 13) : pin.Write(buf, 0, cnt) : Loop While cnt > 0
                                       pin.Close() : isr.Close()
                                    End Sub)
    Dim oswCnt As Long = 0
    If osw IsNot Nothing Then _
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub()
                                       Dim buf(2 ^ 13) As Char, cnt As Integer, pout As StreamReader = p.StandardOutput
                                       Do : cnt = pout.ReadBlock(buf, 0, 2 ^ 13) : osw.Write(buf, 0, cnt) : oswCnt += cnt : Loop While cnt > 0
                                       osw.Close() : pout.Close()
                                    End Sub)

    Dim wasExit As Boolean = p.WaitForExit(10000)
End Using
```

To reproduce the wrong behavior, use

```
Dim outputFilename As String = Nothing
```

in above code (line 2).

Am I missing something on the redirection part? Why is simple input-only redirection working with `sort.exe`, but not with `find.exe`? The code is supposed to work in an automated environment, so I need to make sure that at least the code is running identically every time. Also, other users shall be able to configure custom Queues. Would it help to generally advice to redirect both Input- and OutputStreams?

Comment: Some programs only work properly if both stdin and stdout are redirected.  Xcopy.exe is by far the most notorious example.  Maybe Find.exe too, this doesn't exactly get put to the test very often since it is so trivial to replace.  Which is of course the best way to get ahead.

Comment: Thank you for that information, Hans. Is there a source where this and other known examples are listed (or even explained)? I will then advice in my documentation to always redirect both streams if any (Output to dummy). Please promote your comment to an answer so I can mark this as solved.